# Determine if Generic Class Implements Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, fluent-nhibernate, sharp-architecture

I'm working on a sharp-architecture project that mixes fluent mappings and auto mappings. A basic sharp-architecture project already has a method (AutoMappingConfiguration.ShouldMap) that determines if a type should be automatically mapped or not. Mine currently looks like this:

```
    public override bool ShouldMap(System.Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(ActiveUser))
            return false;

        return type.GetInterfaces().Any(x =>
             x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityWithTypedId<>));
    }
```

Essentially the type ActiveUser is mapped using a fluent mapping and everything else is mapped using auto mapping, except for the generic base classes of course. I'm at the point where I will be adding more fluently mapped classes and really don't want to keep adding if statements to this method to exclude them. I basically need the method

```
bool ShouldMap(System.Type type)
```

to return true if the generic class

```
ClassMap<type>
```

exists.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the generic type using [Type.MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) so assuming you have an assembly which contains all the mappings you can do:

```
public bool ShouldMap(Assembly mappingAssembly, Type type)
{
    Type classMapType = typeof(ClassMap<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    return mappingAssembly.GetTypes().Any(t => t.IsSubclassOf(classMapType));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you considered mapping ALL of the classes, but using a [Mapping**Override**](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Overrides) for the classes you want to map explicitly (instead of regular fluent mapping)?